# C++ Cannot create std::thread after using std::signal

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, signals

I am using signal to test for the existence of an illegal instruction:

std::signal(SIGILL, signalHandler);

If the signalHandler fails then I create a loop counter timer thread:

std::thread myTimer(aTimer);

If I create the thread before the signal test all is fine but if i attempt to create the thread after using signal the program gets aborted.

Here is the code

```
int Use_rdtscp = 0;

void aTimer(void)
{
    for (timerCounter = 0; ; timerCounter++);
}

typedef void(*SignalHandlerPointer)(int);
static SignalHandlerPointer previousHandler;

void SignalHandler(int signal)
{
    throw "Illegal instruction!";
}

void Test_stdscp_function(void)
{
    register uint64_t time1;
    uint32_t junk = 0;

    std::signal(SIGILL, SignalHandler);

    try
    {
        time1 = __rdtscp(&junk); /* READ TIMER */
        printf("rdtscp timer is available.\n");
        Use_rdtscp = 1;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        printf("rdtscp timer is not available. Using counter timer.\n");
        std::signal(SIGILL, SIG_DFL);
        Use_rdtscp = 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int testing = 0;
    //std::thread myTimer(aTimer); // works here

    Test_stdscp_function();

    if (Use_rdtscp == 0)
    {
        std::thread myTimer(aTimer); // but fails if moved to here
    }
```

If the stdscp timer is available then I don't need the thread so I would like to be able to create the thread conditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myTimer` goes out of scope and is destroyed at the closing brace. [A destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) of `std::thread` instance that hasn't been `join()`ed or `detach()`ed calls `terminate()`.

`signal()` has nothing to do with it. Putting the variable into a short-lived scope does.